# Vertical align not behaving as expected

Tags: css

There are tons of info on the subject but nothing i saw gave me a solution. I have [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Chamster/gfjk4/6/).

I want the outer div to follow the size of the contents. The inner divs are supposed to be pushed upwards, so that both the image and the text starts at the top edge. I can't say which will be the tallest element.

How can i solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to vertically align both the image container and the text container in order for this to work correctly. Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/GSQqL/